# Перевести строку в транслит на Python

Tags: python

Как можно перевести строку в транслит с помощью Python? Нужно ли пользоваться сторонней библиотекой или есть встроенная какая-нибудь?

```
 a = "Мальчики и девочки"
```

а должно стать:

```
 malchiki i devochki
```

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/transliterate/

Comment: есть ещё встроенная функция translate(), погуглите, если не хотите сторониих библиотек

Comment: В примере еще и без .lower() не обошлось :)

Comment: нет, без него можно обойтись, в первом комментарии ответ, он позволяет не использовать .lower()

Answer (score 4):

> [transliterate](http://pypi.org/project/transliterate)

```
pip3 install transliterate # or pip for python 2.x
```

```
from transliterate import translit, get_available_language_codes
text = "Privet"
print(translit(text, 'ru'))
```